# Dynamics CRM 2011 SOAP RetrieveMultiple query ignoring criteria

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I am connecting to Dynamics CRM 2011 Online using PHP and SOAP and have come across an issue. The following RetrieveMultiple ignores my criteria and returns all records.

All I want is any contacts that have 'test@test.com' as their email address.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my Criteria/Condition below?

Thanks!

```
<RetrieveMultiple xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
   <query xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:QueryExpression">
      <b:ColumnSet>
         <b:AllColumns>false</b:AllColumns>
         <b:Columns xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <c:string>firstname</c:string>
         </b:Columns>
      </b:ColumnSet>
      <b:Criteria>
         <b:Conditions>
            <b:Condition>
               <b:AttributeName>emailaddress1</b:AttributeName>
               <b:Operator>Equal</b:Operator>
               <b:Values>
                  <b:Value i:type="xsd:string">test@test.com</b:Value>
               </b:Values>
            </b:Condition>
         </b:Conditions>
         <b:FilterOperator>And</b:FilterOperator>
         <b:Filters />
      </b:Criteria>
      <b:Distinct>false</b:Distinct>
      <b:EntityName>contact</b:EntityName>
      <b:LinkEntities />
      <b:PageInfo>
         <b:Count>250</b:Count>
         <b:PageNumber>1</b:PageNumber>
         <b:PagingCookie i:nil="true" />
         <b:ReturnTotalRecordCount>false</b:ReturnTotalRecordCount>
      </b:PageInfo>
   </query>
</RetrieveMultiple>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a few things wrong with the above query. (in particular some of my aliases were confused). As suggested by Jeff Xiong the SOAPLogger helped me.

The criteria was also incorrect. Working soap below:

```
<RetrieveMultiple xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <query xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" i:type="b:QueryExpression">
      <b:ColumnSet>
         <b:AllColumns>false</b:AllColumns>
         <b:Columns xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <c:string>firstname</c:string>
            <c:string>emailaddress1</c:string>
         </b:Columns>
      </b:ColumnSet>
      <b:Criteria>
         <b:Conditions>
            <b:ConditionExpression>
               <b:AttributeName>emailaddress1</b:AttributeName>
               <b:Operator>Equal</b:Operator>
               <b:Values xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                  <c:anyType xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d:string">test@test.com</c:anyType>
               </b:Values>
            </b:ConditionExpression>
         </b:Conditions>
         <b:FilterOperator>And</b:FilterOperator>
         <b:Filters />
      </b:Criteria>
      <b:Distinct>false</b:Distinct>
      <b:EntityName>contact</b:EntityName>
      <b:LinkEntities />
      <b:PageInfo>
         <b:Count>250</b:Count>
         <b:PageNumber>1</b:PageNumber>
         <b:PagingCookie i:nil="true" />
         <b:ReturnTotalRecordCount>false</b:ReturnTotalRecordCount>
      </b:PageInfo>
   </query>
</RetrieveMultiple>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use following SOAP format:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <request i:type="a:RetrieveMultipleRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Parameters xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>Query</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:QueryExpression">
              <a:ColumnSet>
                <a:AllColumns>false</a:AllColumns>
                <a:Columns xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                  <c:string>firstname</c:string>
                </a:Columns>
              </a:ColumnSet>
              <a:Criteria>
                <a:Conditions>
                  <a:ConditionExpression>
                    <a:AttributeName>emailaddress1</a:AttributeName>
                    <a:Operator>Equal</a:Operator>
                    <a:Values xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                      <c:anyType i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">abc@a.com</c:anyType>
                    </a:Values>
                  </a:ConditionExpression>
                </a:Conditions>
                <a:FilterOperator>And</a:FilterOperator>
                <a:Filters />
                <a:IsQuickFindFilter>false</a:IsQuickFindFilter>
              </a:Criteria>
              <a:Distinct>false</a:Distinct>
              <a:EntityName>contact</a:EntityName>
              <a:LinkEntities />
              <a:Orders />
              <a:PageInfo>
                <a:Count>0</a:Count>
                <a:PageNumber>0</a:PageNumber>
                <a:PagingCookie i:nil="true" />
                <a:ReturnTotalRecordCount>false</a:ReturnTotalRecordCount>
              </a:PageInfo>
              <a:NoLock>false</a:NoLock>
            </b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
        <a:RequestName>RetrieveMultiple</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
```

BTW. you can use SOAPLogger where was located in SDK\samplecode\cs\client\soaplogger to get the correct SOAP expression.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff your reply seems 100% valid the only reason I didn't mark it as the answer was because using the SOAPLogger I got a result that is in the same format as my question.

Comment: Did you use QueryExpression to generate the SOAP format? If yes, you shoudl use this statments to add ConditionExpression: yourquery.criteria.addcondition(new conditionexpresison())

Comment: Correct the Query expression I used was the following


QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
      {
          EntityName = "contact",
          ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("firstname"),
          Criteria = new FilterExpression()
          {
              Conditions = {
                  new ConditionExpression
                  {
                      AttributeName = "emailaddress1",
                      Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                      Values = { "test@test.com" }
                  }
              }
          }
      };

Comment: Seems your QueryExpression is fine. Below is my QueryExpression: QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
      query.EntityName = "contact";
      query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[]{"firstname"});
      query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("emailaddress1", ConditionOperator.Equal, "abc@a.com"));